# ModalPopUp Displaying after LinkButton Postback

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, modalpopupextender, linkbutton

After spending hours on it i still couldnt find the Solution,Plaese Help.

I am Developing a Website where I have a Gridview with data,i have a linkbutton as a templatefield in one of the Columns which onClick is doing a postback and displaying the records in a modalpoupextender,which is inside a seperate asp panel,

i have edit,update,delete buttons in that popup which are doing postback and functioning well.

Remmember i have not used UpdatePanel anywhere,as i do not have that kind of requirement.

Now,i have another LinkButton on the Page(not in gridview),which has some other functinality after OnClick postback,the problem is When i Click That LinkButton it first displays the ModalpopUp and then it does the postback and completes the function.The important part is that the Modal PopUp disappears just in seconds.

So,i just get a glimpse of Modalpopup whenever i click on the LinkButton.

I tried ModalPopUpExtender1.hide() at  every Possible Place,but its not Working.

I am not sure how to disable that popup from appearing on LinkButton Click.Please Help me on it.I am in Trouble.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my GridView Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dg_Task" runat="server"  CssClass="gridview"  
                             BorderWidth="1px" 
                        Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="Small" AllowSorting="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="dg_Task_RowDataBound" 
                        Width="100%" Height="143px" 
                        onprerender="mergeDoc">
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_tid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ID") %>' 
                                            Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Lnk" ForeColor="Black" 
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' Font-Underline="False" onclick="Title_Click" 
                                            Text='<%# Bind("Task") %>' Font-Names="Trebuchet MS"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="35%" />
                                    <ItemStyle Height="2px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is The CodeBehind:

```
protected void Title_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ddown_status.Items.Clear();
            var btnId = sender as LinkButton;
            string id = btnId.CommandArgument;

            btnUpdate.CommandArgument = id.ToString();
            btnDelete.CommandArgument = id.ToString();

           //Some  Code which fills the details of my PopUp Fields

              this.modalPopUpExtender1.Show();

}
```

Here is the another LinkButton(On Main Page) code:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

//here even i simple postback(Without any code) Triggers The PoPUp and Provides a Glimpse then the rest code runs

//sample code here
        }
```

Please Help .Thanks

Comment: The panel/div which you assigned in  PopupControlID="". In that control put style="display:none;".